# Can anyone help me how to tag particular version to apache and nginx

Tags: ansible

I have trouble in setting up version for apache and nginx for below playbook.

```yaml
---
 - name: Install appache restart apache and install git
   hosts: all
   become: true

   tasks: 
    - name : install appache2
      package : name=apache2 state=present 

    - name : restart appache2
      command : systemctl restart apache2
      command : systemctl stop apache2

    - name : uninstall appache2
      package : name=apache2 state=absent

    - name : Install git
      package : name=git state=present

    - name : install nginx
      package : name=nginx state=present
```

Comment: did my answer help ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

***I will write the examples as if you want to install apache v4.23 (supposedly it exists in your distribution and available in your package repository)***

If you are using RHEL distros (Centos - Redhat // Or **yum** as package manager), that would be the format you will be using "**$packagename-$version**"

```
    # Apache package name on RHEL is httpd, just putting apache for comparison.

tasks: 
    - name: install apache2
      package:
        name: apache2-4.23
        state: present
```

Compared to if you are using **apt** for package management, that would be the format "**$packagename=$version**"

```
    tasks: 
    - name: install apache2
      package:
        name: apache2=4.23
        state: present
```

*And generally it is one of the above 2 syntaxes.. So if you are not sure, try once with "-".. If it does not work, try with "=".*

And on a side note, use service module to restart your services instead of using the command module

```
    tasks: 
    - name: restart apache2
      service:
        name: apache2
        state: started
```